# nginx: make internal redirect to a different `location` block

Tags: nginx

`try_files`' signature is `try_files file ... uri;`, so one usually uses it to perform tasks like *serve file1 if it exists otherwise serve file2 if it exists otherwise pass the decision to a different `location` block (the one for the mentioned `uri`)*.

Can I somehow use the last part only? That means, do not try to serve any files, just pass the request to a different `location` block. The simple idea of not mentioning any files fails with `nginx: [emerg] invalid number of arguments in "try_files" directive`.

A workaround is to write `try_files /does/not/exist.html /some/uri;` but it looks ugly and possibly incurs a penalty for checking the existence of the nonexistent file.

For context, why do I need this?

I have a config like

```
location /path/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/index.html =404;
    alias /some/dir/;
    expires 604800;
}
```

This unfortunately doesn't match `/path` (no trailing `/`). One could simply write `location /path`, but it is said to [cause path traversals](https://github.com/yandex/gixy/blob/master/docs/en/plugins/aliastraversal.md).

My idea is to add one more handler like

```
location = /path {
  <do the same as for /path/>
}
```

I could of course copy the `alias` and `try_files` there, but that way I would also have to copy the `expires` directive and possible others and keep them synced.

Comment: You could use `rewrite ^ /path/ last;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `rewrite` is good here, just add a block `location` `/path` and use rewrite to redirect the request to the `/path/` block, like this

```
location = /path {
    rewrite ^ /path/ last;
}

location /path/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/index.html =404;
    alias /some/dir/;
    expires 604800;
}
```